# What is the default encoding for a string under VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, encoding

I have a simple question about string. Consider following code:

```
Dim S1 as String = "abc"
```

What is the encoding for S1? Is that UTF-8 or depending on user windows local setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.String` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Characters) to use UTF-16 internally.

Answer (score 5):

It's an implementation detail you *should* not need to worry about (unless you leave the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), in which case things get complicated since [`Char`s represent UTF-16 code units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)).

When it becomes relevant, i.e., when the string is converted into a byte array, you have to *choose* the encoding to use:

```
Dim S1 As String = ...

Dim utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S1)
Dim utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(S1)

Dim western As New Encoding(1252)
Dim westernBytes = western.GetBytes(S1)
```

Comment: It becomes relevant way earlier than that. Try sticking a character from outside the BMP in a string and get it out by addressing characters from the string. UTF-16 in .NET leaks all over the place, most particular in that `System.Char` is 16 bits wide and thus cannot hold all characters (representing a code *unit*, not a code *point*). This is in contrast to Python where the internal encoding can be various things but you are guaranteed that you won't notice from using Unicode strings. In .NET you'll notice as soon as you leave the BMP.

Comment: The Basic Multilingual Plane. I.e. the first 65536 Unicode code points of which the characters can be addressed in a single UTF-16 code unit each.

Comment: @Joey: Thanks. I've extended my answer.

Comment: `Dim western As New Encoding(1252)` should be `Dim western = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`